# Pylint no VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, configuração

Estou começando a usar o `VSCode` para trabalhar com `Python`, e gostaria de configurar o `Pylint` para que destacasse os erros|warnings enquanto digito (como o `PyCharm` faz), por padrão os lints só são 'executados' no `VSCode` quando eu salvo o arquivo... Tem como mudar esse comportamento? Dá pra configurar o `Pylint` pra que se comporte como no `PyCharm` e verifique o código enquanto ainda estou escrevendo ele?

Minhas configurações do VSCode (Settings.json) para Python são as seguintes:

```
    "python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe", 
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--disable=missing-docstring"
    ],
```

Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, rodar enquanto tu ta programando acho que não é possível, um solução para isso seria tu diminuir o tempo entre os salvamentos automáticos do `VSCode`, assim ele salva sozinho com mais frequência e já aplica o `PyLint`.

Acessa as preferências do teus `VSCode`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acessa `Text Editor`, `Files` e na opção `Auto-save delay` coloca o tempo que desejar entre os salvamentos automáticos. O valor `default` é 1000ms.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa é essa é uma possibilidade! Venho do `JS` e sempre deixava essa opção desabilitada pra não gerar erro ou problemas como loop infinito no `Vue/React` etc... pensei que com o `Django` pudesse ter o mesmo efeito mas já vi que não tem. Obrigada.